# How can I find xpath for a class name and generic attribute?

Tags: html, xpath

```
<div class="abc" def="23"/>


//div[contains(@class,'abc')]
```

I can't use this xpath because the class name is used in other places as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could combine two conditions using the `and` statement in your `XPath` expression as follows:

```
//div[@class="abc" and @def="23"]
```

**[Example](http://xpathfiddle.net/PHMJLH)**

Answer (score 2):

gtlambert's answer should work for your specific example, but generally when you are matching on class names, you should use `contains()` with space-padding, because a class attribute could contain more than one class:

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' abc ') and @def = '23']
```